# How do you call a method from a different package?

Tags: java, menu, click, package, menuitem

I cant figure out how to call this method from the different package becuase what i want to do is make a close method that will close a frame but i cant figure out how to call it!

First Package:

```
JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // This below for some reason does not work!

            close c = new close();
            c.closer();
        }
    });
    mnMenu.add(mntmExit);
```

Second Package:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class close extends JFrame {

    public close() {}

    public void closer() {

        WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent( winClosingEvent );

    }
}
```

Comment: *"I cant [sic] figure out how to call this method"* -- The code in your First Package isn't a method, it's just a bunch of loose code.  You need to enclose it in an actual method before you can call it (e.g. `public methodName() { JMenuItem mntmExit ... }`)

Comment: i just took the part in the code i am having a problem with for the first package because the whole class is very big!

Comment: Nevertheless, if you are asking about how to call a method, you need to show us the method you want to call.  If the method is long, feel free to leave any functionality that isn't related to being able to call it out of the posted method body, but we need to see a method definition.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of the second package should be imported.

So suppose the class 'Close' (I suggest to call it 'Close' instead of 'close') is in a package called 'second.pack', then the first class should have an import statement as follows:

```
import second.pack.Close;
```

## More complete example

### First class

```
package first.pack;

import second.pack.Second;

public class First {

    public void method1() {

        Second second = new Second();
        second.method2();

    }
}
```

### Second class

```
package second.pack;

public class Second {

    public void method2() {

    }

}
```